# Is the Subjunctive Mood always a conditional statement?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, mood

I had exam and they asked: I would go to the library every day, if I ____ you.

Options:

- were
- was

I came to know upon reading that question was in subjunctive mood. So, my question is

what is the difference between subjunctive mood and conditional statement?

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229772/whats-the-truth-about-the-subjunctive-and-conditional-statements-anyway?rq=1)

Comment: A conditional statement has two parts, a condition and a result (protasis/apodosis). The subjunctive mood can be used in a variety of situations for a variety of purposes. A statement with the subjunctive mood can be a conditional, or not. A conditional statement can use the subjunctive mood, or not. These are two orthogonal things.

Comment: "If you answer my question, I will be happy" is an example of a conditional with no subjunctive. "I demand that my question be answered" is an example of subjunctive with no conditional.

Comment: The up votes makes me suspect there are others who might appreciate an answer to the question :D

Comment: Caroline, why would you want to compare the two? What do you think "subjunctive mood" may have to do with "conditional statement"? Can you expand your question?

Comment: See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: @RegDwigнt "... *if* clauses in (counterfactual) sentences are conventionally always in the past subjunctive in English. " See Looper's comment above for link.

Comment: @Kris not sure why you felt the urge to tell me that, or how it relates to anything that I said, or to the question at hand for that matter. Same for your bit about votes. Complete non sequitur. Ease up on the coffee, mate.